# How do i calculate the difference with in jquery each function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following XML document

```
var xml = '<t0><t1><t20>6267</t20></t1><t1><t20>556</t20></t1></t0>';
```

How do i calculate the difference which is  (6267-556) and push it array

```
var myarray = [];
var xml = '<t0><t1><t20>6267</t20></t1><t1><t20>556</t20></t1></t0>';
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$(xml).find('t1').each(function () {
    var difference = $(this).find('t20').text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLxsd4xt/

Answer (score 2):

```
var myarray = [];
var xml = '<t0><t1><t20>6267</t20></t1><t1><t20>556</t20></t1></t0>';
$xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
var a = $(xml).find('t20').eq(0).text();
var b = $(xml).find('t20').eq(1).text();
myarray.push(a-b);
console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: nice simple solution .

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of ways to do it, here's one (it will subtrack all other `t20` values from the first one, so you're not limited to two numbers):

```js
var myarray = [];
var xml = '<t0><t1><t20>6267</t20></t1><t1><t20>556</t20></t1></t0>';
var difference = false;

$(xml).find('t1').each(function () {
    if (difference === false) { // compare by type in case first num is 0
        difference = $(this).find('t20').text(); // assign the first number
    } else {
        difference -= $(this).find('t20').text(); // subtract the others
    }
});
myarray.push(difference);
alert('The difference is: ' + difference);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, no reason to complicate things.

Comment: Note, you can also optimize your selectors (if that's the definitive structure of the xml) to: `$(xml).find('t1 t20').each...`

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, there are tons of ways, so heres another. 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pLxsd4xt/5/)

```
var myarray = [];
var xml = '<t0><t1><t20>6267</t20></t1><t1><t20>556</t20></t1></t0>';

var difference = null;
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$(xml).find('t1').each(function () {
    var to_subtract = parseInt($(this).find('t20').text());
    difference = (difference == null ? to_subtract : difference - to_subtract);
});
    console.log(difference);
    console.log(Math.abs(difference));
```

Comment: Not sure who upvoted this, but it's definitely **NOT** the difference but the negative sum...

Comment: @Shomz thats why I left the Math.abs() at the bottom

Comment: To get the positive sum? Still not a difference... Quick math: `6267 - 556 = 5711`... not `-6823` nor `+6823`...

Comment: @Shomz ahahahah.  whoops my mistake.  I'm quite spacy today it would seem.  updated answer.  nice catch :D

Comment: Hehe, yeah, that null looked weird. :)